# regexp group repetition in python

Tags: python, regex

```
string = "input-ports 6012, 6017, 6016"
m = re.match("input-ports(\s\d{4},?)(\s\d{4},?)(\s\d{4},?)", string)
print m.groups #=> (' 6012,', ' 6017,', ' 6016')
```

But when I want to use group repetition, it only return the last number

```
m = re.match("input-ports(\s\d{4},?)+", string)
print m.groups #=> (' 6016',)
```

anyone can tell me why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While traditional regex engines remember and return only the last match, some advanced libs provide `captures` property which holds all matches for the given group. There's a library called [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) for python that does that, among other nice things:

```
import regex

string = "input-ports 6012, 6017, 6016"
m = regex.match("input-ports(?:\s(\d{4}),?)+", string)
print m.captures(1) # ['6012', '6017', '6016']
```

If you can't use this library, the only workaround is to use `findall` and replace the repetition with a single group with lookaheads. This is not always possible, but your example is easy:

```
import re

string = "input-ports 6012, 6017, 6016"
m = re.findall("(?<=\s)\d{4}(?=,|$)", string)
print m # ['6012', '6017', '6016']
```

Answer (score 3):

> Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
>   Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all
>   iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not
>   interested in the data

on regex101

Comment: Could you provide the resulting regexp after the modifications you suggest ? (instead of only giving the way to modify the regexp). Thanks

Comment: @brunetton dont use the capturing group and use it like this https://regex101.com/r/x0aSJI/1  `(\d{4})`